# I can "print(args.username) but I can't use args.username as a value for a search?

Tags: python, argparse

I have been trying to debug my program. I am accepting an argument for the username through argparse and want to use the args.username value to search the passwd file. I am getting the following error: **NameError: name 'args' is not defined**. I can do a print(args.username) but I can't use args.username in my search.

```
import argparse


# My argparse section
def main():
    # initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my argparse script")

    # add the parameters positional/optional
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', nargs='+', help="Enter user name to search passwd file with", type=str)

    # parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # This print statement works fine
    print(args.username)
    print(args)


# My search the passwd file section
# The statement below, user=args.username is causing the error
user = args.username
with open("passwd") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.split(":")[0] == user:
            print("User found      : " + line.split(":")[0])
        else:
            print("User not found  : " + line.split(":")[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `args` only exists inside your `main()` method.  Also, where you have your `user = args.username` line, you haven't even ran the `main()` method yet.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Confusingly, they shouldn't see the `print` in `main` "working fine", because they'd die with an exception before it's even invoked. So this isn't an [MCVE] that demonstrates the behavior claimed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Wow, I didn't even notice that.  I just noticed that the code was outside of the method and assumed that was the issue without fully thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is in the scope of `main()`. And, `main()` is running after your search code, since your search code is outside of any function. Since your search is outside of `main`'s scope, it doesn't have access to `args`. You could un-indent the search so it'll be within scope, allowing you to use `args`. This will have the effect of running the search at the end of `main()` instead of before, so not only will `args` be defined, but it'll also be in scope:

```
import argparse


# My argparse section
def main():
    # initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my argparse script")

    # add the parameters positional/optional
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', nargs='+', help="Enter user name to search passwd file with", type=str)

    # parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # This print statement works fine
    print(args.username)
    print(args)


    # My search the passwd file section
    # The statement below, user=args.username is causing the error
    user = args.username
    with open("passwd") as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.split(":")[0] == user:
                print("User found      : " + line.split(":")[0])
            else:
                print("User not found  : " + line.split(":")[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You mentioned you could do `print(args.username)` in `main()` just fine, which seems like that'd only be possible if you removed your search code, since the search code would error before `main()` even ran in the code you've shown. So I'm thinking your example isn't the code in which that print worked.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. I forgot to note that user = "David" works fine but user = args.username is causing the error. From all of your comments and suggestion I was able to get past the error. Thanks!!

Comment: Last question on this topic. I am not getting the error anymore, but when I pass the argument -u=root to args.username and compare that to the passwd file, I do not get a match. I opened the passwd file and there is a user named root. If I hardcode user = "root" instead of passing the value via args.username it works fine.

Comment: @zeusbella it's usually recommend that you ask a new question regarding any separate issues. However I'd try some simple debugging first; does `args.username` have the exact length you'd expect? Like, have you made sure there's no whitespace or anything like that? And when you print it out, you're seeing the value you expect?